# how to get lib_mysqludf_sys.dll file on windows

Tags: mysql, dll, user-defined-functions, lib

Anybody knows where can i find the lib_mysqludf_sys.dll file? It doesn't matter if it is 32bits or 64. I've been looking but i can't find it. Or ther is a way to install the file instead of download it?

Comment: `lib_mysqludf_sys.dll` is installed with a MySQL server installation.

Comment: i installed mysql 8.0 and 5.5 and it does not.

Comment: oh it a custom dll. can be downloaded here https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/2965   (there are links called repository and lib_mysqludf_sys_64.zip)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you so so so so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the page there is a lib_mysqludf_sys.dll.zip that works perfectly. https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/2965